# List of strings to tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

Good evening,

I am trying to make a tuple out of a list of strings. It does however not behave as expected. Can anyone enlighten me?

```
l = ['NP', 'shot'] 
tups = map(lambda x: tuple(x), l[-1]) 
# Desired result
print(tups) #('shot')

# Result
print(tups) #  [('s',), ('h',), ('o',), ('t',)]
# or
print(tups) # <map object at 0x000000001691FD00>
```

Comment: Do you want to convert `['NP', 'shot']` to `('NP', 'shot')`?

Comment: Just use `(l[-1],)`

Comment: `('shot')` is actually not a tuple. `('shot',)` is...

Comment: the title and the actual question don't match , see comment #1, please edit your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use brackets:

```
l = ['NP', 'shot'] 
tups = (l[-1],)
print(tups) # ('shot')
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to be using the built in tuple() function for this

```py
    l = ['NP', 'shot'] 
    tups = tuple(l)
    print(tups)
```

Comment: she wants ('shot') not ('NP', 'shot')

Comment: I am answering the question as asked in the title and in the text. If I googled "List of Strings to tuples in python" I would want to see the tuple() built in.

Comment: No, my answer is not wrong to the question as asked, She simply asked to convert a list of strings into a tuple.  This is the list of strings, as a tuple.  I am not going to count a comment as a necessary part of the question. You can give an answer to the comment , but as someone who is often very irritated with complicated answers to simple questions on SO, I am going to leave the answer that I would appreciate if I were googling the question.

Comment: look at everyone elses answer, they all give ('shot') or ('shot',) none are like yours and she stated she is asking for ('shot') your answer is wrong

Comment: and also she stated list of strings to tuple*s* and not list of strings to tuple

Comment: Everyone else can answer the comment, I'm answering the question as asked.

Answer (score 1):

If, just as a thought experiment, you want `map` to work you would do:

```
>>> l = ['NP', 'shot'] 
>>> next(map(lambda x: (x,), [l[-1]]))
('shot',)
```

It is far better to just do:

```
>>> tuple([l[-1]])
('shot',)
```

Or use the literal tuple constructor form:

```
>>> (l[-1],)
('shot',)
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
>>> l[-1],
('shot',)
```

With `tuple([l[-1]])` you need a iterable container -- in this case a list -- so that you don't get `('s', 'h', 'o', 't')`

You don't need that with `(l[-1],)` since the arguments to the literal are not iterated; they are only evaluated:

```
>>> (1+2,)     #1+2 will be evaluated
(3,)

>>> ("1+2",)   # the string "1+2" is not iterated...
('1+2',)

>>> tuple(1+2)  # self explanatory error...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

>>> tuple("1+2")   # string is iterated char by char
('1', '+', '2')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
tuple(map(str, l[-1].split(",")))
```

its in literal form tho

Comment: And why is this hated? it gives the same answer as others

Comment: Splitting the last string by comma and mapping the list with `str` are completely unnecessary and irrelevant to the question.